# Conditional formatting with pandas.ExcelWriter: unable to change format by hand and read format back with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I am saving a pandas dataframe as Excel with pandas.ExcelWriter, formatting some cells in red with conditional_format.

The formatting succeeds, but I am then unable to read the formatting information back using openpyxl.load_workbook: when I ask for the color of the cell I have colored, the answer is always "None". See the code below, which prints the following (notice the "rgb=None" in the last line):

```
Cell value: apple
Font info:
<openpyxl.styles.fonts.Font object>
Parameters:
name='Calibri', charset=None, family=2.0, b=False, i=False, strike=None, outline=None, shadow=None, condense=None, color=<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
auto=None, tint=0.0, type='theme', theme=1, rgb=None, indexed=None, extend=None, sz=11.0, u=None, vertAlign=None, scheme='minor'
```

Moreover, the color of the cell seems locked (i.e., I cannot change it manually after the Excel has been saved).
Is there a way to fix these issues?

Many thanks in advance!

(NB. I am using Python 3.5, pandas==0.22.0, openpyxl==2.6.2)

```
    import pandas as pd
    from openpyxl import load_workbook

    # SAVING SAMPLE EXCEL FILE WITH ONE CELL COLORED IN RED

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('MyExcel.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['FRUIT', 'ANIMAL'], data = [['apple', 'cow'], ['banana', 'cat'], ['pear', 'zebra']])

    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'sheet_1', header = True, index = False)

    fmt = writer.book.add_format({'font_color' : 'red'})
    writer.sheets['sheet_1'].conditional_format('A2', {'type' : 'unique', 'format' : fmt})

    writer.close()

    # READING FORMATTING INFORMATION BACK

    wb = load_workbook("MyExcel.xlsx", read_only = True)
    ws = wb['sheet_1']

    print("Cell value: {}\nFont info:\n{}".format(ws.cell(2,1).value,     ws.cell(2,1).font))

    wb.close()
```

*** UPDATE: changing the formatting code to

```
 cell_format = writer.book.add_format()
 cell_format.set_font_color('red')
 writer.sheets['sheet_1'].write('A2', 'apple', cell_format)
```

solves the issue.

Comment: You have applied a conditional format to A2. This is not the same as a cell style. BTW you might find it easier to use openpyxl for both writing and reading the file.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Switching to cell style solved the issue